# How to add custom string "api" after the context in the url in Springboot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am creating a test SpringBoot Application, I want all my rest endpoints to have "api" string added to all the urls. 
For example :

`http://localhost:8080/MyApp/api/students`

I tried adding 
`server.servlet.context-path=/api`
but it did not help.

Comment: `@RequestMapping("/api/students")`

Comment: Please try  : spring.data.rest.basePath=/api

Comment: @JBNizet : Don't want to add "api" manually in each api. I want some config which will automatically all api url having "api" as string

Comment: @zpavel : why spring data ?

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two options

Option 1. 
Global setting which affects all paths from all controllers. Add the following setting in your application.properties file from your Spring app

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

Option 2. 
Local setting which you can apply to one individual controller and which affects all methods inside it.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class YourController
{
```